Problem with loading .h5 weights into modellib.MaskRCNN model
I downloaded the mask_rcnn_coco.h5 weights from https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN. I want to run a training on pretrained model using this weights. But when I try to run the weights using folling code:
COCO_WEIGHTS_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")

config = CustomConfig()
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training", config=config,
                                  model_dir=DEFAULT_LOGS_DIR)

weights_path = COCO_WEIGHTS_PATH
        # Download weights file

if not os.path.exists(weights_path):
  utils.download_trained_weights(weights_path)s

model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True, exclude=[
                "mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",
                "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])

train(model)    

I get an error NotImplementedError: Save or restore weights that is not an instance of tf.Variable is not supported in h5, use save_format='tf' instead. Got a model or layer Conv2D with weights [<KerasVariable shape=(7, 7, 3, 64), dtype=float32, path=conv1/kernel>, <KerasVariable shape=(64,), dtype=float32, path=conv1/bias>]
I tried to load the weights and then save them but the error is keep encountered. Is there any way to fix that issue?

Hi mask_rcnn package is outdated, because it uses old versions of tensorflow and keras. I would suggest importing model from torchvision.
# Packages that I'm using
# torch Version: 2.3.0
# torch Version: 0.18.0

from torchvision.models.detection import MaskRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights, maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn
import torch



# model = maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=MaskRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights.DEFAULT)
model = maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=MaskRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights.COCO_V1)

model.eval()
x = [torch.rand(3, 300, 400), torch.rand(3, 500, 400)]
predictions = model(x)

